# Strucked in Center aligning of a Mobile Menu click Point

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the HTML code of the mobile menu →

```
   <a class="toggle-button">
                    <span class="minus minus-top"></span>
                    <span class="minus minus-middle"></span>
                    <span class="minus minus-bottom"></span>
   </a>
```

There is a lot of CSS written, but this is the main CSS that might be effecting →

```
.clicked span.minus-middle{
  margin-left:-100px;
  opacity:0;
}

.toggle-button span.minus-top{
  top:-10px;
}

.toggle-button span.minus-bottom{
  bottom:-17px;
}
```

My problem is I am unable to align this at center in such a fashion that irrespective of the size of the logo it should vertically be centered in the middle.

There is a property →

```
vertical-align: middle
```

But i think that works only when we have choose table and table-cell. **Can you find the fix for my menu?**

The entire code for browser testing can be found here → 
[Click the Link](http://trafficopedia.com/htmlpost.com/)

Comment: Do you want to align "burger menu" to the center of the navigation menu on mobile view? For now, I don't see any code in your question what at least tries to implement this functionality. Please first try implementing something and then head up to SO to ask what is wrong with your implementation, because there is none for now.

Comment: Yes I want to align burger menu just next to the logo or in the middle of the whole header box. exactly in the vertical middle irrespective of the height of the logo. Did you get me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change top : 1px to 25 px as below.

```
.toggle-button {
top:25px
}
```

or

```
 .toggle-button {margin-top: 50%;}
```

Comment: Let me try this margin-top: 50% and upate you.

Comment: I tried same to setup in your site on my browser and it worked.

Comment: Still not in middle somewhat more tilted towards bottom. May be some padding/margin causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using html you can do like this

```
<a class="toggle-button">
    <center>
        <span class="minus minus-top">aa</span></br>
        <span class="minus minus-middle">aa</span></br>
        <span class="minus minus-bottom">aa</span></br>
    </center>
</a>
```

Comment: Did you add the</br> after each statement?

Comment: you need this aa vertically downward...right? aligned at center?I'm getting the o/p

Comment: I don't know hat you are saying mam.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure but would this work:

```
margin-right: 45%
```

or maybe the :

```
<center></center>
```

but it is looked down on.